# Issue with Image modal controls, possibly z-index issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog, responsive

Im having issues with a modal gallery in my website that I'm running on localhost. I have inserted a gallery made from a plugin into the site. The gallery looks great and is responsive, when I click on an image to activate the modal, the controls are semi view-able but not functioning when clicked. I thought the issue was with the buttons being underneath the modal but the issue persisted after I adjusted the z-index. Any thoughts? Thanks http://testing123.emcfintech.com

Comment: Can you include your css?

Comment: Just added the CSS, thanks for taking a look!